# Syntax for updating new database table with similar data from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, triggers

I'm trying to set a trigger that will update another table I have (customers) when `wp_meta` is populate. So, basically, when data is added to `wp_meta`, I want certain fields in my `customers` table updated. For instance, when `first_name` and `last_name` is updated in `wp_meta`, I want `first_name` and `last_name` updated with the same info.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_customers AFTER UPDATE ON wp_usermeta
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    customers.first_name = wp_meta.first_name;
    END
```

I keep getting a syntax error, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. I have also set the delimiter to `//`.

The other problem is that the database `wp_meta` is based on a key/value system. So you have `wp_meta.metakey` and a related `wp_metavalue`. I"m lost on how to get the value from the key.

Comment: Have you read the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)?

Comment: Yes, and I'm still lost.

Comment: haveing identical data in 2 tables like this sounds like poor design

Comment: Weird, the examples shown in the german version of the manual don't appear in the english version...Have a look at the example here --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Comment: @Dagon it sounds like it, but it's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_customers AFTER UPDATE ON wp_usermeta
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update customers set customers.first_name = new.first_name where customers.id=new.id;
    END
```

(not tested...)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Lajos is a good start. However, I would add (1) the reason your trigger definition fails is that the SQL between the "BEGIN" and "END" keywords is not a valid SQL statement and (2) you'll also want to create a trigger for the AFTER INSERT event as well, otherwise you'll only get customer data when the wp_userdata table is updated, not when the records are originally inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_wp_usermeta_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON wp_usermeta
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update customers set customers.first_name = new.first_name where customers.id=new.id;
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_wp_usermeta_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON wp_usermeta
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update customers set customers.first_name = new.first_name where   customers.id=new.id;
    END;
```